# How to use DataGridView value as save & load control in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm currently making save & load options program with DataGridView. the save button will save picturebox coordinates to make lines based on what already drawn on the picturebox. Multiple save datas are saved as tables in DataGridView. When loaded, the saved coordinates in tables go back to the screen and draw the saved coordinate lines. in the future gonna make the save data can be exported & imported to excel files but for now those buttons is not working yet.

Questions is How to make multiple loads possible? the first save data can be loaded properly after click but the 2nd and next will make the app crashed so the only working save data are the top ones. the error always points to `string lineCell = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();` but I dont know how to fix it

also if have suggestions how to export & import it to excel file please tell me. Thank you very much.

More or less the app is like this

[image: main]

used code for load & delete buttons in datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[7].Index)
                {
                    string lineCell = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    int x1Cell = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                    int y1Cell = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                    int x2Cell = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                    int y2Cell = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                    if (lineCell == "Black")
                    {
                        lineComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        line1X1 = x1Cell;
                        line1Y1 = y1Cell;
                        line1X2 = x2Cell;
                        line1Y2 = y2Cell;
                    }
                    else if (lineCell == "Red")
                    {
                        lineComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
                        line2X1 = x1Cell;
                        line2Y1 = y1Cell;
                        line2X2 = x2Cell;
                        line2Y2 = y2Cell;
                    }
                    else if (lineCell == "Yellow")
                    {
                        lineComboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
                        line3X1 = x1Cell;
                        line3Y1 = y1Cell;
                        line3X2 = x2Cell;
                        line3Y2 = y2Cell;
                    }
                        lineComboBox.Refresh();
                        pictureBox1.Refresh();
                }
                else if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[8].Index)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
                }
            }
```

Save Button code

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = "Save " + index.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = ang;
            if(lineComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = "Black";
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = line1X1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = line1Y1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = line1X2;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = line1Y2;
            }
            else if(lineComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = "Red";
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = line2X1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = line2Y1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = line2X2;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = line2Y2;
            }
            else if (lineComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = "Yellow";
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = line3X1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = line3Y1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = line3X2;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = line3Y2;
            }
        }
```

and this is the error message. Sorry its in japanese the office only use japanese version here. but its roughly translated as this

Unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional Information: Index out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya added the error message but sorry its in japanese. already translated there

Comment: `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex]` or `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[1]` triggered the exception. Check if the `dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count` is lower than `rowIndex`. Check `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells.Count` is lower than `1`.

Comment: @Han sorry I dont understand. can you give more detailed instruction please? thank you very much

Comment: before you access the row and cell you have to make sure they exist! `SelectedRows[rowIndex].Cells[1]` maybe that rowIndex doesn't exist or cells[1] doesnt exist. check if rowIndex is between 0 and dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1

Comment: You can look at your vairables (hover over them in debug mode), particularly what rows are you trying to select versus what rows are present in `DataGridView`. Also note, that for such scenarios it is *way* better to work with `DataTable` (which you'd set as `DataGridView's` `DataSource`), rather then values taken directly from `DataGridView`. It's way faster and safe (i.e. `DataTypes` are defined). If you gonna draw hundreds of lines, that `DGV`'s gonna be a big draw back.